# Exception in Run time

Tags: android, exception

These errors seems to be occasional and I cannot reproduce them. From stack I can learn that such error may occurs for my different layout resources.

Can anybody explain why this error occurs? And what I can do to fix this problem?

```
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matineeapplicationlayer/com.example.matineeapplicationlayer.MatineeAPP}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #822: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #822: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.example.matineeapplicationlayer.MatineeAPP.onCreate(MatineeAPP.java:13)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 11 more
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 30 more
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1869)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
06-03 12:30:30.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 33 more




package com.example.matineeapplicationlayer;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MatineeAPP extends Activity
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.matinee_app);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post whatever XML you're trying to inflate.

Comment: How big are the graphic files that you use in your layout? What is the max heap setting of you emulator device? What is the resolution of the emulated device?

Comment: Seems the cause is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: 10.1 in WXGA tablet (1080*800mdpi)

Comment: _@Cornholio am using only one XML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atlast found the problem its due to the out of memory, have to increase the RAM and Heap value of the Emulator, because my application is large so it consumes larger memory,

thanks for every one